# Script to import all cities of India in SQL server table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to imports all states and cities of India in SQL Server table(2008). The table format is as below.

ID    CityName   StateName

I have tried to find any links or script on google but did not get anything. 
How can I do so.???

Comment: Are you asking where you can find a list of cities and states in India? Or how to put the content of such list into that table?

Comment: In fact I want information for both.

Answer (score 14):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state_list` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `state_list`
--

INSERT INTO `state_list` (`id`, `state`) VALUES
(1, 'ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS'),
(2, 'ANDHRA PRADESH'),
(3, 'ARUNACHAL PRADESH'),
(4, 'ASSAM'),
(5, 'BIHAR'),
(6, 'CHATTISGARH'),
(7, 'CHANDIGARH'),
(8, 'DAMAN AND DIU'),
(9, 'DELHI'),
(10, 'DADRA AND NAGAR HAVELI'),
(11, 'GOA'),
(12, 'GUJARAT'),
(13, 'HIMACHAL PRADESH'),
(14, 'HARYANA'),
(15, 'JAMMU AND KASHMIR'),
(16, 'JHARKHAND'),
(17, 'KERALA'),
(18, 'KARNATAKA'),
(19, 'LAKSHADWEEP'),
(20, 'MEGHALAYA'),
(21, 'MAHARASHTRA'),
(22, 'MANIPUR'),
(23, 'MADHYA PRADESH'),
(24, 'MIZORAM'),
(25, 'NAGALAND'),
(26, 'ORISSA'),
(27, 'PUNJAB'),
(28, 'PONDICHERRY'),
(29, 'RAJASTHAN'),
(30, 'SIKKIM'),
(31, 'TAMIL NADU'),
(32, 'TRIPURA'),
(33, 'UTTARAKHAND'),
(34, 'UTTAR PRADESH'),
(35, 'WEST BENGAL'),
(36, 'TELANGANA');
```

Comment: complete table for indian states

Answer (score 8):

Here what you want !!!!

```
create table all_cities (
city_name text,
city_code text,
state_code text
);

create table all_states (
state_code text,
state_name text,
country_code text
);

-- Andaman & Nicobar
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Alipur', '101','1'),
VALUES('Andaman Island', '102','1'),
VALUES('Anderson Island', '103','1'),
VALUES('Arainj-Laka-Punga', '104','1'),
VALUES('Austinabad', '105','1'),
VALUES('Bamboo Flat', '106','1'),
VALUES('Barren Island', '107','1'),
VALUES('Beadonabad', '108','1'),
VALUES('Betapur', '109','1'),
VALUES('Bindraban', '110','1'),
VALUES('Bonington', '111','1'),
VALUES('Brookesabad', '112','1'),
VALUES('Cadell Point', '113','1'),
VALUES('Calicut', '114','1'),
VALUES('Chetamale', '115','1'),
VALUES('Cinque Islands', '116','1'),
VALUES('Defence Island', '117','1'),
VALUES('Digilpur', '118','1'),
VALUES('Dolyganj', '119','1'),
VALUES('Flat Island', '120','1'),
VALUES('Geinyale', '121','1'),
VALUES('Great Coco Island', '122','1'),
VALUES('Haddo', '123','1'),
VALUES('Havelock Island', '124','1'),
VALUES('Henry Lawrence Island', '125','1'),
VALUES('Herbertabad', '126','1'),
VALUES('Hobdaypur', '127','1'),
VALUES('Ilichar', '128','1'),
VALUES('Ingoie', '128','1'),
VALUES('Inteview Island', '130','1'),
VALUES('Jangli Ghat', '131','1'),
VALUES('Jhon Lawrence Island', '132','1'),
VALUES('Karen', '133','1'),
VALUES('Kartara', '134','1'),
VALUES('KYD Islannd', '135','1'),
VALUES('Landfall Island', '136','1'),
VALUES('Little Andmand', '137','1'),
VALUES('Little Coco Island', '138','1'),
VALUES('Long Island', '138','1'),
VALUES('Maimyo', '140','1'),
VALUES('Malappuram', '141','1'),
VALUES('Manglutan', '142','1'),
VALUES('Manpur', '143','1'),
VALUES('Mitha Khari', '144','1'),
VALUES('Neill Island', '145','1'),
VALUES('Nicobar Island', '146','1'),
VALUES('North Brother Island', '147','1'),
VALUES('North Passage Island', '148','1'),
VALUES('North Sentinel Island', '149','1'),
VALUES('Nothen Reef Island', '150','1'),
VALUES('Outram Island', '151','1'),
VALUES('Pahlagaon', '152','1'),
VALUES('Palalankwe', '153','1'),
VALUES('Passage Island', '154','1'),
VALUES('Phaiapong', '155','1'),
VALUES('Phoenix Island', '156','1'),
VALUES('Port Blair', '157','1'),
VALUES('Preparis Island', '158','1'),
VALUES('Protheroepur', '159','1'),
VALUES('Rangachang', '160','1'),
VALUES('Rongat', '161','1'),
VALUES('Rutland Island', '162','1'),
VALUES('Sabari', '163','1'),
VALUES('Saddle Peak', '164','1'),
VALUES('Shadipur', '165','1'),
VALUES('Smith Island', '166','1'),
VALUES('Sound Island', '167','1'),
VALUES('South Sentinel Island', '168','1'),
VALUES('Spike Island', '169','1'),
VALUES('Tarmugli Island', '170','1'),
VALUES('Taylerabad', '171','1'),
VALUES('Titaije', '172','1'),
VALUES('Toibalawe', '173','1'),
VALUES('Tusonabad', '174','1'),
VALUES('West Island', '175','1'),
VALUES('Wimberleyganj', '176','1'),
VALUES('Yadita', '177','1');


-- Andhra Pradesh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Adilabad', '201','2'),
VALUES('Anantapur', '201','2'),
VALUES('Chittoor', '203','2'),
VALUES('Cuddapah', '204','2'),
VALUES('East Godavari', '205','2'),
VALUES('Guntur', '206','2'),
VALUES('Hyderabad', '207','2'),
VALUES('Karimnagar', '208','2'),
VALUES('Khammam', '209','2'),
VALUES('Krishna', '210','2'),
VALUES('Kurnool', '211','2'),
VALUES('Mahabubnagar', '212','2'),
VALUES('Medak', '213','2'),
VALUES('Nalgonda', '214','2'),
VALUES('Nellore', '215','2'),
VALUES('Nizamabad', '216','2'),
VALUES('Prakasam', '217','2'),
VALUES('Rangareddy', '218','2'),
VALUES('Srikakulam', '219','2'),
VALUES('Visakhapatnam', '220','2'),
VALUES('Vizianagaram', '221','2'),
VALUES('Warangal', '222','2'),
VALUES('West Godavari', '223','2');



-- Arunachal Pradesh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Anjaw', '301','3'),
VALUES('Changlang', '302','3'),
VALUES('Dibang Valley', '303','3'),
VALUES('East Kameng', '304','3'),
VALUES('East Siang', '305','3'),
VALUES('Itanagar', '306','3'),
VALUES('Kurung Kumey', '307','3'),
VALUES('Lohit', '308','3'),
VALUES('Lower Dibang Valley', '309','3'),
VALUES('Lower Subansiri', '310','3'),
VALUES('Papum Pare', '311','3'),
VALUES('Tawang', '312','3'),
VALUES('Tirap', '313','3'),
VALUES('Upper Siang', '314','3'),
VALUES('Upper Subansiri', '315','3'),
VALUES('West Kameng', '316','3'),
VALUES('West Siang', '317','3');

-- Assam
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Barpeta', '401','4'),
VALUES('Bongaigaon', '402','4'),
VALUES('Cachar', '403','4'),
VALUES('Darrang', '404','4'),
VALUES('Dhemaji', '405','4'),
VALUES('Dhubri', '406','4'),
VALUES('Dibrugarh', '407','4'),
VALUES('Goalpara', '408','4'),
VALUES('Golaghat', '409','4'),
VALUES('Guwahati', '410','4'),
VALUES('Hailakandi', '411','4'),
VALUES('Jorhat', '412','4'),
VALUES('Kamrup', '413','4'),
VALUES('Karbi Anglong', '414','4'),
VALUES('Karimganj', '415','4'),
VALUES('Kokrajhar', '416','4'),
VALUES('Lakhimpur', '417','4'),
VALUES('Marigaon', '418','4'),
VALUES('Nagaon', '419','4'),
VALUES('Nalbari', '420','4'),
VALUES('North Cachar Hills', '421','4'),
VALUES('Silchar', '422','4'),
VALUES('Sivasagar', '423','4'),
VALUES('Sonitpur', '424','4'),
VALUES('Tinsukia', '425','4'),
VALUES('Udalguri', '426','4');


-- Bihar
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Araria', '501','5'),
VALUES('Aurangabad', '502','5'),
VALUES('Banka', '503','5'),
VALUES('Begusarai', '504','5'),
VALUES('Bhagalpur', '505','5'),
VALUES('Bhojpur', '506','5'),
VALUES('Buxar', '507','5'),
VALUES('Darbhanga', '508','5'),
VALUES('East Champaran', '509','5'),
VALUES('Gaya', '510','5'),
VALUES('Gopalganj', '511','5'),
VALUES('Jamshedpur', '512','5'),
VALUES('Jamui', '513','5'),
VALUES('Jehanabad', '514','5'),
VALUES('Kaimur (Bhabua)', '515','5'),
VALUES('Katihar', '516','5'),
VALUES('Khagaria', '517','5'),
VALUES('Kishanganj', '518','5'),
VALUES('Lakhisarai', '519','5'),
VALUES('Madhepura', '520','5'),
VALUES('Madhubani', '521','5'),
VALUES('Munger', '522','5'),
VALUES('Muzaffarpur', '523','5'),
VALUES('Nalanda', '524','5'),
VALUES('Nawada', '525','5'),
VALUES('Patna', '526','5'),
VALUES('Purnia', '527','5'),
VALUES('Rohtas', '528','5'),
VALUES('Saharsa', '529','5'),
VALUES('Samastipur', '530','5'),
VALUES('Saran', '531','5'),
VALUES('Sheikhpura', '532','5'),
VALUES('Sheohar', '533','5'),
VALUES('Sitamarhi', '534','5'),
VALUES('Siwan', '535','5'),
VALUES('Supaul', '536','5'),
VALUES('Vaishali', '537','5'),
VALUES('West Champaran', '538','5');



-- Chandigarh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Chandigarh', '601','6'),
VALUES('Mani Marja', '602','6');


-- Chhattisgarh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bastar', '701','7'),
VALUES('Bhilai', '702','7'),
VALUES('Bijapur', '703','7'),
VALUES('Bilaspur', '704','7'),
VALUES('Dhamtari', '705','7'),
VALUES('Durg', '706','7'),
VALUES('Janjgir-Champa', '707','7'),
VALUES('Jashpur', '708','7'),
VALUES('Kabirdham-Kawardha', '709','7'),
VALUES('Korba', '710','7'),
VALUES('Korea', '711','7'),
VALUES('Mahasamund', '712','7'),
VALUES('Narayanpur', '713','7'),
VALUES('Norh Bastar-Kanker', '714','7'),
VALUES('Raigarh', '715','7'),
VALUES('Raipur', '716','7'),
VALUES('Rajnandgaon', '717','7'),
VALUES('South Bastar-Dantewada', '718','7'),
VALUES('Surguja', '719','7');


-- Dadra & Nagar Haveli
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Amal', '801','8'),
VALUES('Amli', '802','8'),
VALUES('Bedpa', '803','8'),
VALUES('Chikhli', '804','8'),
VALUES('Dadra & Nagar Haveli', '805','8'),
VALUES('Dahikhed', '806','8'),
VALUES('Dolara', '807','8'),
VALUES('Galonda', '808','8'),
VALUES('Kanadi', '809','8'),
VALUES('Karchond', '810','8'),
VALUES('Khadoli', '811','8'),
VALUES('Kharadpada', '812','8'),
VALUES('Kherabari', '813','8'),
VALUES('Kherdi', '814','8'),
VALUES('Kothar', '815','8'),
VALUES('Luari', '816','8'),
VALUES('Mashat', '817','8'),
VALUES('Rakholi', '818','8'),
VALUES('Rudana', '819','8'),
VALUES('Saili', '820','8'),
VALUES('Sili', '821','8'),
VALUES('Silvassa', '822','8'),
VALUES('Sindavni', '823','8'),
VALUES('Udva', '824','8'),
VALUES('Umbarkoi', '825','8'),
VALUES('Vansda', '826','8'),
VALUES('Vasona', '827','8'),
VALUES('Velugam', '828','8');


-- Daman and Diu
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Brancavare', '901','9'),
VALUES('Dagasi', '902','9'),
VALUES('Daman', '903','9'),
VALUES('Diu', '904','9'),
VALUES('Magarvara', '905','9'),
VALUES('Nagwa', '906','9'),
VALUES('Pariali', '907','9'),
VALUES('Passo Covo', '908','9');


-- Delhi
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Central Delhi', '1001','10'),
VALUES('East Delhi', '1002','10'),
VALUES('New Delhi', '1003','10'),
VALUES('North Delhi', '1004','10'),
VALUES('North East Delhi', '1005','10'),
VALUES('North West Delhi', '1006','10'),
VALUES('Old Delhi', '1007','10'),
VALUES('South Delhi', '1008','10'),
VALUES('South West Delhi', '1009','10'),
VALUES('West Delhi', '1010','10');

--  Goa
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Canacona', '1101','11'),
VALUES('Candolim', '1102','11'),
VALUES('Chinchinim', '1103','11'),
VALUES('Cortalim', '1104','11'),
VALUES('Goa', '1105','11'),
VALUES('Jua', '1106','11'),
VALUES('Madgaon', '1107','11'),
VALUES('Mahem', '1108','11'),
VALUES('Mapuca', '1109','11'),
VALUES('Marmagao', '1110','11'),
VALUES('Panji', '1111','11'),
VALUES('Ponda', '1112','11'),
VALUES('Sanvordem', '1113','11'),
VALUES('Terekhol', '1114','11');


-- Gujarat
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Ahmedabad', '1201','12'),
VALUES('Amreli', '1202','12'),
VALUES('Anand', '1203','12'),
VALUES('Banaskantha', '1204','12'),
VALUES('Baroda', '1205','12'),
VALUES('Bharuch', '1206','12'),
VALUES('Bhavnagar', '1207','12'),
VALUES('Dahod', '1208','12'),
VALUES('Dang', '1209','12'),
VALUES('Dwarka', '1210','12'),
VALUES('Gandhinagar', '1211','12'),
VALUES('Jamnagar', '1212','12'),
VALUES('Junagadh', '1213','12'),
VALUES('Kheda', '1214','12'),
VALUES('Kutch', '1215','12'),
VALUES('Mehsana', '1216','12'),
VALUES('Nadiad', '1217','12'),
VALUES('Narmada', '1218','12'),
VALUES('Navsari', '1219','12'),
VALUES('Panchmahals', '1220','12'),
VALUES('Patan', '1221','12'),
VALUES('Porbandar', '1222','12'),
VALUES('Rajkot', '1223','12'),
VALUES('Sabarkantha', '1224','12'),
VALUES('Surat', '1225','12'),
VALUES('Surendranagar', '1226','12'),
VALUES('Vadodara', '1227','12'),
VALUES('Valsad', '1228','12'),
VALUES('Vapi', '1229','12');


-- Haryana
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Ambala', '1301','13'),
VALUES('Bhiwani', '1302','13'),
VALUES('Faridabad', '1303','13'),
VALUES('Fatehabad', '1304','13'),
VALUES('Gurgaon', '1305','13'),
VALUES('Hisar', '1306','13'),
VALUES('Jhajjar', '1307','13'),
VALUES('Jind', '1308','13'),
VALUES('Kaithal', '1309','13'),
VALUES('Karnal', '1310','13'),
VALUES('Kurukshetra', '1311','13'),
VALUES('Mahendragarh', '1312','13'),
VALUES('Mewat', '1313','13'),
VALUES('Panchkula', '1314','13'),
VALUES('Panipat', '1315','13'),
VALUES('Rewari', '1316','13'),
VALUES('Rohtak', '1317','13'),
VALUES('Sirsa', '1318','13'),
VALUES('Sonipat', '1319','13'),
VALUES('Yamunanagar', '1320','13');


-- Himachal Pradesh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bilaspur', '1401','14'),
VALUES('Chamba', '1402','14'),
VALUES('Dalhousie', '1403','14'),
VALUES('Hamirpur', '1404','14'),
VALUES('Kangra', '1405','14'),
VALUES('Kinnaur', '1406','14'),
VALUES('Kullu', '1407','14'),
VALUES('Lahaul & Spiti', '1408','14'),
VALUES('Mandi', '1409','14'),
VALUES('Shimla', '1410','14'),
VALUES('Sirmaur', '1411','14'),
VALUES('Solan', '1412','14'),
VALUES('Una', '1413','14');



-- Jammu & Kashmir
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Anantnag', '1501','15'),
VALUES('Baramulla', '1502','15'),
VALUES('Budgam', '1503','15'),
VALUES('Doda', '1504','15'),
VALUES('Jammu', '1505','15'),
VALUES('Kargil', '1506','15'),
VALUES('Kathua', '1507','15'),
VALUES('Kupwara', '1508','15'),
VALUES('Leh', '1509','15'),
VALUES('Poonch', '1510','15'),
VALUES('Pulwama', '1511','15'),
VALUES('Rajauri', '1512','15'),
VALUES('Srinagar', '1513','15'),
VALUES('Udhampur', '1514','15');



-- Jharkhand
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bokaro', '1601','16'),
VALUES('Chatra', '1602','16'),
VALUES('Deoghar', '1603','16'),
VALUES('Dhanbad', '1604','16'),
VALUES('Dumka', '1605','16'),
VALUES('East Singhbhum', '1606','16'),
VALUES('Garhwa', '1607','16'),
VALUES('Giridih', '1608','16'),
VALUES('Godda', '1609','16'),
VALUES('Gumla', '1610','16'),
VALUES('Hazaribag', '1611','16'),
VALUES('Jamtara', '1612','16'),
VALUES('Koderma', '1613','16'),
VALUES('Latehar', '1614','16'),
VALUES('Lohardaga', '1615','16'),
VALUES('Pakur', '1616','16'),
VALUES('Palamu', '1617','16'),
VALUES('Ranchi', '1618','16'),
VALUES('Sahibganj', '1619','16'),
VALUES('Seraikela', '1620','16'),
VALUES('Simdega', '1621','16'),
VALUES('West Singhbhum', '1622','16');


-- Karnataka
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bagalkot', '1701','17'),
VALUES('Bangalore', '1702','17'),
VALUES('Bangalore Rural', '1703','17'),
VALUES('Belgaum', '1704','17'),
VALUES('Bellary', '1705','17'),
VALUES('Bhatkal', '1706','17'),
VALUES('Bidar', '1707','17'),
VALUES('Bijapur', '1708','17'),
VALUES('Chamrajnagar', '1709','17'),
VALUES('Chickmagalur', '1710','17'),
VALUES('Chikballapur', '1711','17'),
VALUES('Chitradurga', '1712','17'),
VALUES('Dakshina Kannada', '1713','17'),
VALUES('Davanagere', '1714','17'),
VALUES('Dharwad', '1715','17'),
VALUES('Gadag', '1716','17'),
VALUES('Gulbarga', '1717','17'),
VALUES('Hampi', '1718','17'),
VALUES('Hassan', '1719','17'),
VALUES('Haveri', '1720','17'),
VALUES('Hospet', '1721','17'),
VALUES('Karwar', '1722','17'),
VALUES('Kodagu', '1723','17'),
VALUES('Kolar', '1724','17'),
VALUES('Koppal', '1725','17'),
VALUES('Madikeri', '1726','17'),
VALUES('Mandya', '1727','17'),
VALUES('Mangalore', '1728','17'),
VALUES('Manipal', '1729','17'),
VALUES('Mysore', '1730','17'),
VALUES('Raichur', '1731','17'),
VALUES('Shimoga', '1732','17'),
VALUES('Sirsi', '1733','17'),
VALUES('Sringeri', '1734','17'),
VALUES('Srirangapatna', '1735','17'),
VALUES('Tumkur', '1736','17'),
VALUES('Udupi', '1737','17'),
VALUES('Uttara Kannada', '1738','17');


-- Kerala
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Alappuzha', '1801','18'),
VALUES('Alleppey', '1802','18'),
VALUES('Alwaye', '1803','18'),
VALUES('Ernakulam', '1804','18'),
VALUES('Idukki', '1805','18'),
VALUES('Kannur', '1806','18'),
VALUES('Kasargod', '1807','18'),
VALUES('Kochi', '1808','18'),
VALUES('Kollam', '1809','18'),
VALUES('Kottayam', '1810','18'),
VALUES('Kovalam', '1811','18'),
VALUES('Kozhikode', '1812','18'),
VALUES('Malappuram', '1813','18'),
VALUES('Palakkad', '1814','18'),
VALUES('Pathanamthitta', '1815','18'),
VALUES('Perumbavoor', '1816','18'),
VALUES('Thiruvananthapuram', '1817','18'),
VALUES('Thrissur', '1818','18'),
VALUES('Trichur', '1819','18'),
VALUES('Trivandrum', '1820','18'),
VALUES('Wayanad', '1821','18');


-- Lakshadweep
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Agatti Island', '1901','19'),
VALUES('Bingaram Island', '1902','19'),
VALUES('Bitra Island', '1903','19'),
VALUES('Chetlat Island', '1904','19'),
VALUES('Kadmat Island', '1905','19'),
VALUES('Kalpeni Island', '1906','19'),
VALUES('Kavaratti Island', '1907','19'),
VALUES('Kiltan Island', '1908','19'),
VALUES('Lakshadweep Sea', '1909','19'),
VALUES('Minicoy Island', '1910','19'),
VALUES('North Island', '1911','19'),
VALUES('South Island', '1912','19');


-- Madhya Pradesh
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Anuppur', '2001','20'),
VALUES('Ashoknagar', '2002','20'),
VALUES('Balaghat', '2003','20'),
VALUES('Barwani', '2004','20'),
VALUES('Betul', '2005','20'),
VALUES('Bhind', '2006','20'),
VALUES('Bhopal', '2007','20'),
VALUES('Burhanpur', '2008','20'),
VALUES('Chhatarpur', '2009','20'),
VALUES('Chhindwara', '2010','20'),
VALUES('Damoh', '2011','20'),
VALUES('Datia', '2012','20'),
VALUES('Dewas', '2013','20'),
VALUES('Dhar', '2014','20'),
VALUES('Dindori', '2015','20'),
VALUES('Guna', '2016','20'),
VALUES('Gwalior', '2017','20'),
VALUES('Harda', '2018','20'),
VALUES('Hoshangabad', '2019','20'),
VALUES('Indore', '2020','20'),
VALUES('Jabalpur', '2021','20'),
VALUES('Jagdalpur', '2022','20'),
VALUES('Jhabua', '2023','20'),
VALUES('Katni', '2024','20'),
VALUES('Khandwa', '2025','20'),
VALUES('Khargone', '2026','20'),
VALUES('Mandla', '2027','20'),
VALUES('Mandsaur', '2028','20'),
VALUES('Morena', '2029','20'),
VALUES('Narsinghpur', '2030','20'),
VALUES('Neemuch', '2031','20'),
VALUES('Panna', '2032','20'),
VALUES('Raisen', '2033','20'),
VALUES('Rajgarh', '2034','20'),
VALUES('Ratlam', '2035','20'),
VALUES('Rewa', '2036','20'),
VALUES('Sagar', '2037','20'),
VALUES('Satna', '2038','20'),
VALUES('Sehore', '2039','20'),
VALUES('Seoni', '2040','20'),
VALUES('Shahdol', '2041','20'),
VALUES('Shajapur', '2042','20'),
VALUES('Sheopur', '2043','20'),
VALUES('Shivpuri', '2044','20'),
VALUES('Sidhi', '2045','20'),
VALUES('Tikamgarh', '2046','20'),
VALUES('Ujjain', '2047','20'),
VALUES('Umaria', '2048','20'),
VALUES('Vidisha', '2049','20');



-- Maharashtra
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Ahmednagar', '2101','21'),
VALUES('Akola', '2102','21'),
VALUES('Amravati', '2103','21'),
VALUES('Aurangabad', '2104','21'),
VALUES('Beed', '2105','21'),
VALUES('Bhandara', '2106','21'),
VALUES('Buldhana', '2107','21'),
VALUES('Chandrapur', '2108','21'),
VALUES('Dhule', '2109','21'),
VALUES('Gadchiroli', '2110','21'),
VALUES('Gondia', '2111','21'),
VALUES('Hingoli', '2112','21'),
VALUES('Jalgaon', '2113','21'),
VALUES('Jalna', '2114','21'),
VALUES('Kolhapur', '2115','21'),
VALUES('Latur', '2116','21'),
VALUES('Mahabaleshwar', '2117','21'),
VALUES('Mumbai', '2118','21'),
VALUES('Mumbai City', '2119','21'),
VALUES('Mumbai Suburban', '2120','21'),
VALUES('Nagpur', '2121','21'),
VALUES('Nanded', '2122','21'),
VALUES('Nandurbar', '2123','21'),
VALUES('Nashik', '2124','21'),
VALUES('Osmanabad', '2125','21'),
VALUES('Parbhani', '2126','21'),
VALUES('Pune', '2127','21'),
VALUES('Raigad', '2128','21'),
VALUES('Ratnagiri', '2129','21'),
VALUES('Sangli', '2130','21'),
VALUES('Satara', '2131','21'),
VALUES('Sholapur', '2132','21'),
VALUES('Sindhudurg', '2133','21'),
VALUES('Thane', '2134','21'),
VALUES('Wardha', '2135','21'),
VALUES('Washim', '2136','21'),
VALUES('Yavatmal', '2137','21');


-- Manipur
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bishnupur', '2201','22'),
VALUES('Chandel', '2202','22'),
VALUES('Churachandpur', '2203','22'),
VALUES('Imphal East', '2204','22'),
VALUES('Imphal West', '2205','22'),
VALUES('Senapati', '2206','22'),
VALUES('Tamenglong', '2207','22'),
VALUES('Thoubal', '2208','22'),
VALUES('Ukhrul', '2209','22');



-- Meghalaya
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('East Garo Hills', '2301','23'),
VALUES('East Khasi Hills', '2302','23'),
VALUES('Jaintia Hills', '2303','23'),
VALUES('Ri Bhoi', '2304','23'),
VALUES('Shillong', '2305','23'),
VALUES('South Garo Hills', '2306','23'),
VALUES('West Garo Hills', '2307','23'),
VALUES('West Khasi Hills', '2308','23');



-- Mizoram
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Aizawl', '2401','24'),
VALUES('Champhai', '2402','24'),
VALUES('Kolasib', '2403','24'),
VALUES('Lawngtlai', '2404','24'),
VALUES('Lunglei', '2405','24'),
VALUES('Mamit', '2406','24'),
VALUES('Saiha', '2407','24'),
VALUES('Serchhip', '2408','24');


-- Nagaland
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Dimapur', '2501','25'),
VALUES('Kohima', '2502','25'),
VALUES('Mokokchung', '2503','25'),
VALUES('Mon', '2504','25'),
VALUES('Phek', '2505','25'),
VALUES('Tuensang', '2506','25'),
VALUES('Wokha', '2507','25'),
VALUES('Zunheboto', '2508','25');



-- Orissa
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Angul', '2601','26'),
VALUES('Balangir', '2602','26'),
VALUES('Balasore', '2603','26'),
VALUES('Baleswar', '2604','26'),
VALUES('Bargarh', '2605','26'),
VALUES('Berhampur', '2606','26'),
VALUES('Bhadrak', '2607','26'),
VALUES('Bhubaneswar', '2608','26'),
VALUES('Boudh', '2609','26'),
VALUES('Cuttack', '2610','26'),
VALUES('Deogarh', '2611','26'),
VALUES('Dhenkanal', '2612','26'),
VALUES('Gajapati', '2613','26'),
VALUES('Ganjam', '2614','26'),
VALUES('Jagatsinghapur', '2615','26'),
VALUES('Jajpur', '2616','26'),
VALUES('Jharsuguda', '2617','26'),
VALUES('Kalahandi', '2618','26'),
VALUES('Kandhamal', '2619','26'),
VALUES('Kendrapara', '2620','26'),
VALUES('Kendujhar', '2621','26'),
VALUES('Khordha', '2622','26'),
VALUES('Koraput', '2623','26'),
VALUES('Malkangiri', '2624','26'),
VALUES('Mayurbhanj', '2625','26'),
VALUES('Nabarangapur', '2626','26'),
VALUES('Nayagarh', '2627','26'),
VALUES('Nuapada', '2628','26'),
VALUES('Puri', '2629','26'),
VALUES('Rayagada', '2630','26'),
VALUES('Rourkela', '2631','26'),
VALUES('Sambalpur', '2632','26'),
VALUES('Subarnapur', '2633','26'),
VALUES('Sundergarh', '2634','26');


-- Pondicherry
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Bahur', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Karaikal', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Mahe', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Pondicherry', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Purnankuppam', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Valudavur', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Villianur', '2701','27'),
VALUES('Yanam', '2701','27');



-- Punjab
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Amritsar', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Barnala', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Bathinda', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Faridkot', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Fatehgarh Sahib', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Ferozepur', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Gurdaspur', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Hoshiarpur', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Jalandhar', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Kapurthala', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Ludhiana', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Mansa', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Moga', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Muktsar', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Nawanshahr', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Pathankot', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Patiala', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Rupnagar', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Sangrur', '2801','28'),
VALUES('SAS Nagar', '2801','28'),
VALUES('Tarn Taran', '2801','28');




-- Rajasthan
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Ajmer', '2901','29'),
VALUES('Alwar', '2902','29'),
VALUES('Banswara', '2903','29'),
VALUES('Baran', '2904','29'),
VALUES('Barmer', '2905','29'),
VALUES('Bharatpur', '2906','29'),
VALUES('Bhilwara', '2907','29'),
VALUES('Bikaner', '2908','29'),
VALUES('Bundi', '2909','29'),
VALUES('Chittorgarh', '2910','29'),
VALUES('Churu', '2911','29'),
VALUES('Dausa', '2912','29'),
VALUES('Dholpur', '2913','29'),
VALUES('Dungarpur', '2914','29'),
VALUES('Hanumangarh', '2915','29'),
VALUES('Jaipur', '2916','29'),
VALUES('Jaisalmer', '2917','29'),
VALUES('Jalore', '2918','29'),
VALUES('Jhalawar', '2919','29'),
VALUES('Jhunjhunu', '2920','29'),
VALUES('Jodhpur', '2921','29'),
VALUES('Karauli', '2922','29'),
VALUES('Kota', '2923','29'),
VALUES('Nagaur', '2924','29'),
VALUES('Pali', '2925','29'),
VALUES('Pilani', '2926','29'),
VALUES('Rajsamand', '2927','29'),
VALUES('Sawai Madhopur', '2928','29'),
VALUES('Sikar', '2929','29'),
VALUES('Sirohi', '2930','29'),
VALUES('Sri Ganganagar', '2931','29'),
VALUES('Tonk', '2932','29'),
VALUES('Udaipur', '2933','29');


-- Sikkim
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Barmiak', '3001','30'),
VALUES('Be', '3002','30'),
VALUES('Bhurtuk', '3003','30'),
VALUES('Chhubakha', '3004','30'),
VALUES('Chidam', '3005','30'),
VALUES('Chubha', '3006','30'),
VALUES('Chumikteng', '3007','30'),
VALUES('Dentam', '3008','30'),
VALUES('Dikchu', '3009','30'),
VALUES('Dzongri', '3010','30'),
VALUES('Gangtok', '3011','30'),
VALUES('Gauzing', '3012','30'),
VALUES('Gyalshing', '3013','30'),
VALUES('Hema', '3014','30'),
VALUES('Kerung', '3015','30'),
VALUES('Lachen', '3016','30'),
VALUES('Lachung', '3017','30'),
VALUES('Lema', '3018','30'),
VALUES('Lingtam', '3019','30'),
VALUES('Lungthu', '3020','30'),
VALUES('Mangan', '3021','30'),
VALUES('Namchi', '3022','30'),
VALUES('Namthang', '3023','30'),
VALUES('Nanga', '3024','30'),
VALUES('Nantang', '3025','30'),
VALUES('Naya Bazar', '3026','30'),
VALUES('Padamachen', '3027','30'),
VALUES('Pakhyong', '3028','30'),
VALUES('Pemayangtse', '3029','30'),
VALUES('Phensang', '3030','30'),
VALUES('Rangli', '3031','30'),
VALUES('Rinchingpong', '3032','30'),
VALUES('Sakyong', '3033','30'),
VALUES('Samdong', '3034','30'),
VALUES('Singtam', '3035','30'),
VALUES('Siniolchu', '3035','30'),
VALUES('Sombari', '3036','30'),
VALUES('Soreng', '3037','30'),
VALUES('Sosing', '3038','30'),
VALUES('Tekhug', '3039','30'),
VALUES('Temi', '3040','30'),
VALUES('Tsetang', '3041','30'),
VALUES('Tsomgo', '3042','30'),
VALUES('Tumlong', '3043','30'),
VALUES('Yangang', '3044','30'),
VALUES('Yumtang', '3045','30');



-- Tamil Nadu
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Chennai', '3101','31'),
VALUES('Chidambaram', '3102','31'),
VALUES('Chingleput', '3103','31'),
VALUES('Coimbatore', '3104','31'),
VALUES('Courtallam', '3105','31'),
VALUES('Cuddalore', '3106','31'),
VALUES('Dharmapuri', '3107','31'),
VALUES('Dindigul', '3108','31'),
VALUES('Erode', '3109','31'),
VALUES('Hosur', '3110','31'),
VALUES('Kanchipuram', '3111','31'),
VALUES('Kanyakumari', '3112','31'),
VALUES('Karaikudi', '3113','31'),
VALUES('Karur', '3114','31'),
VALUES('Kodaikanal', '3115','31'),
VALUES('Kovilpatti', '3116','31'),
VALUES('Krishnagiri', '3117','31'),
VALUES('Kumbakonam', '3118','31'),
VALUES('Madurai', '3119','31'),
VALUES('Mayiladuthurai', '3120','31'),
VALUES('Nagapattinam', '3121','31'),
VALUES('Nagarcoil', '3122','31'),
VALUES('Namakkal', '3123','31'),
VALUES('Neyveli', '3124','31'),
VALUES('Nilgiris', '3125','31'),
VALUES('Ooty', '3126','31'),
VALUES('Palani', '3127','31'),
VALUES('Perambalur', '3128','31'),
VALUES('Pollachi', '3129','31'),
VALUES('Pudukkottai', '3130','31'),
VALUES('Rajapalayam', '3131','31'),
VALUES('Ramanathapuram', '3132','31'),
VALUES('Salem', '3133','31'),
VALUES('Sivaganga', '3134','31'),
VALUES('Sivakasi', '3135','31'),
VALUES('Thanjavur', '3136','31'),
VALUES('Theni', '3137','31'),
VALUES('Thoothukudi', '3138','31'),
VALUES('Tiruchirappalli', '3139','31'),
VALUES('Tirunelveli', '3140','31'),
VALUES('Tirupur', '3141','31'),
VALUES('Tiruvallur', '3142','31'),
VALUES('Tiruvannamalai', '3143','31'),
VALUES('Tiruvarur', '3144','31'),
VALUES('Trichy', '3145','31'),
VALUES('Tuticorin', '3146','31'),
VALUES('Vellore', '3147','31'),
VALUES('Villupuram', '3148','31'),
VALUES('Virudhunagar', '3149','31'),
VALUES('Yercaud', '3150','31');



-- Tripura
INSERT INTO all_cities (city_name,city_code,state_code)
VALUES('Agartala', '3201','32'),
VALUES('Ambasa', '3202','32'),
VALUES('Bampurbari', '3203','32'),
VALUES('Belonia', '3204','32'),
VALUES('Dhalai', '3205','32'),
VALUES('Dharam Nagar', '3206','32'),
VALUES('Kailashahar', '3207','32'),
VALUES('Kamal Krishnabari', '3208','32'),
VALUES('Khopaiyapara', '3209','32'),
VALUES('Khowai', '3210','32'),
VALUES('Phuldungsei', '3211','32'),
VALUES('Radha Kishore Pur', '3212','32'),
VALUES('Tripura', '3213','32');







Insert into all_states (state_code,state_name,country_code) 
VALUES('1', 'Andaman & Nicobar [AN]','+91'),
VALUES('2', 'Andhra Pradesh [AP]','+91'),
VALUES('3', 'Arunachal Pradesh [AR]','+91'),
VALUES('4', 'Assam [AS]','+91'),
VALUES('5', 'Bihar [BH]','+91'),
VALUES('6', 'Chandigarh [CH]','+91'),
VALUES('7', 'Chhattisgarh [CG]','+91'),
VALUES('8', 'Dadra & Nagar Haveli [DN]','+91'),
VALUES('9', 'Daman & Diu [DD]','+91'),
VALUES('10', 'Delhi [DL]','+91'),
VALUES('11', 'Goa [GO]','+91'),
VALUES('12', 'Gujarat [GU]','+91'),
VALUES('13', 'Haryana [HR]','+91'),
VALUES('14', 'Himachal Pradesh [HP]','+91'),
VALUES('15', 'Jammu & Kashmir [JK]','+91'),
VALUES('16', 'Jharkhand [JH]','+91'),
VALUES('17', 'Karnataka [KR]','+91'),
VALUES('18', 'Kerala [KL]','+91'),
VALUES('19', 'Lakshadweep [LD]','+91'),
VALUES('20', 'Madhya Pradesh [MP]','+91'),
VALUES('21', 'Maharashtra [MH]','+91'),
VALUES('22', 'Manipur [MN]','+91'),
VALUES('23', 'Meghalaya [ML]','+91'),
VALUES('24', 'Mizoram [MM]','+91'),
VALUES('25', 'Nagaland [NL]','+91'),
VALUES('26', 'Orissa [OR]','+91'),
VALUES('27', 'Pondicherry [PC]','+91'),
VALUES('28', 'Punjab [PJ]','+91'),
VALUES('29', 'Rajasthan [RJ]','+91'),
VALUES('30', 'Sikkim [SK]','+91'),
VALUES('31', 'Tamil Nadu [TN]','+91'),
VALUES('32', 'Tripura [TR]','+91'),
VALUES('33', 'Uttar Pradesh [UP]','+91'),
VALUES('34', 'Uttaranchal [UT]','+91'),
VALUES('35', 'West Bengal [WB]','+91');
```

Comment: Uttar Pradesh, Uttaranchal and WestBengal City data is missing. Could you please provide those too? Thanks!

Comment: Sure not able to add here exceed limit so please go find the missing one here https://justpaste.it/547wp @NiveditMajumdar

Answer (score 0):

Census by Govt.Of India
http://www.censusindia.gov.in/towns/town.aspx
It can be a good source for State and Cities list,but you have to do copy paste work

You can make two tables:

1. state_tbl
   -STATE_ID
   -STATE_NAME
2. city_tbl
   -CITY_ID
   -CITY_NAME
   -STATE_ID

Comment: what is the syntax for import data from excel in sql??

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

> **SQL QUERY FOR STATES IN INDIA**

```
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ANDHRA PRADESH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ASSAM');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ARUNACHAL PRADESH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('GUJRAT');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('BIHAR');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('HARYANA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('HIMACHAL PRADESH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('JAMMU & KASHMIR');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('KARNATAKA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('KERALA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('MADHYA PRADESH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('MAHARASHTRA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('Telangana');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('MANIPUR');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('MEGHALAYA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('MIZORAM');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('NAGALAND');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ORISSA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('PUNJAB');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('RAJASTHAN');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('SIKKIM');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('TAMIL NADU');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('TRIPURA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('UTTAR PRADESH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('WEST BENGAL');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('GOA');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('PONDICHERY');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('LAKSHDWEEP');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('DAMAN & DIU');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('DADRA & NAGAR');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('CHANDIGARH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ANDAMAN & NICOBAR');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('UTTARANCHAL');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('JHARKHAND');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('CHATTISGARH');  
INSERT INTO master_state_table(name) VALUES ('ASSAM');
```